# Erwine Kryszeg's INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS, Section 1.5-8

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In Section 1.5-8, in his book, INTRODUCTORY FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS WITH APPLICATIONS, Kryszeg tries to show that the set $X$ of all polynomials defined on a given closed interval $[a,b]$ on the real line, regarded as a subspace of the metric space $C[a,b]$ under the metric 
$$d(x,y) \colon= \max_{t\in[a,b]} |x(t) - y(t) |$$ for all $x$, $y \in C[a,b]$, is not complete. The author invites the reader to consider a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to a continuous function not a polynomial.

Now how to explicitly form such a sequence? And how to show that this sequence converges uniformly to a continuous function which is not a polynomial?

Comment: try the Taylor series of an exponential

Comment: Thanks, but this much I already had in mind. But how to demonstrate the uniform convergence? And how to show that the limit is not a polynomial?

Comment: $exp$ is not a polynomial, as all polynomials will have higher derivatives equals zero.

Answer (score 2):

For example, try the Taylor polynomials for $\exp$.

Comment: I thought so, but I'm unable, I'm afraid, to show rigorously on an arbitrary closed interval $[a,b]$ the uniform convergence and that the limit is NOT a polynomial.

Comment: An explicit form of Taylor's remainder theorem shows uniform convergence

Comment: More generally, given an analytic function f in domain D and point p in D, the Taylor series of f at p converges uniformly to f on any closed disk centred at p and contained in D.

Comment: If you want an easier, very explicit, example, try the Maclaurin series for $1/(1-x)$ with $-1 < a < b < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The classical way of doing this is through the heat kernel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel. This is essentially Weierstrass' original construction used to approximate continuous functions with polynomials. Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, and extend it to be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ by linearly extending $f$ to vanish outside of $[a-1,b+1]$. Define a new function $(H_{t}f)(x)$ by
$$
   (H_{t}f)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4t}f(y)\,dy,\;\;\; t > 0.
$$
The function $(H_{t}f)(x)$ converges uniformly to $f$ as $t\downarrow 0$. So, for $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $t_{0} > 0$ such that $|f-H_{t_{0}}f| < \epsilon/2$ for all $a \le x \le b$. Then, there exists $N > 0$ such that
$$
              \left|(H_{t_{0}}f)(t)-\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!\sqrt{4\pi t_{0}}}\int_{a-1}^{b+1}\left(\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{4t_{0}}\right)^{n}f(y)\,dy\right| < \epsilon/2,
   \;\;\; a \le t \le b.
$$
It then follows that the polynomial in $x$ shown below is uniformly within $\epsilon$ of $f$ on $[a,b]$:
$$
            P_{n}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{n!\sqrt{4\pi t_{0}}}\int_{a-1}^{b+1}\left(\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{4t_{0}}\right)^{n}f(y)\,dy.
$$

Comment: Use Weierstrass approximation theorem . This theorem  proof tell you everything about construction and convergence.

Comment: @User420 : $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.